# Show $\sup_{x\in[0,2]}|f(x)| \geq |f^\prime (x)|$ for a certain differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f(x)$ has a continuous derivative and $f(0)=f(2)=0$.

Let $M=\sup_{x\in[0,2]}|f(x)|$.

Prove that if $M\geq|f'(x)|$ for all $x\in [0,2]$, then $M=0$.

I have already proved that there is at least one $\xi\in[0,2]$ such that $|f'(\xi)|\geq M$, and if $M\geq|f'(x)|$ holds, then there must be $\xi_1, \xi_2$ such that $|f'(\xi_1)|=|f'(\xi_2)|=M$.

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: $M\geq|f(x)|$ for all $x\in[0,2]$ automatically by the definition of the supremum

Comment: sorry!mistyping on line 4 and 6,it should be $|f'(x)|$ instead of $|f(x)|$

Comment: Try to show that there is a $\xi$ such that $|f'(\xi)|>M$ so that the conditions cannot be met (unless $M=0$).

Comment: Perhaps, assume $M>0$ and break into cases, according to where $a$, with $f(a)=M$, lives. If $a<1$, apply MVT on $[0,a]$. If $a\ge 1$, apply MVT on $[a,2]$ (the slope of the associated secant lines are no smaller than $M$).

Comment: Along with @DavidMitra's suggestion, you can use the fact that $f'(a)=0$.

Comment: along with@DavidMitra 's suggestion ,I cannot get contradiction if $a=1$,through this ,I can get that if and only if $a=1$ will this assumption($M>0$) stand.To go further,I try to use  a corollary :if $g(x)$ is continuous,then $|g(x)|$ is also continuous,to find out some good propertie of $f'(x)$ itself. But there seems to be no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in a comment that you can reduce the problem to the case $a=1$. So suppose $a=1$, and $M>0$. Without loss of generality, we may suppose that $f(1)$ is positive. We know that $f'(1)=0$, so we can find $x<1$ that is close enough to $1$ so that the point $(x,f(x))$ lies above the straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,M)$. But then the Mean Value Theorem tells us that there must exist $\xi\in(0,x)$ such that $f'(\xi)>M$, a contradiction.

Comment: thanks! I previously ignored that we can find out a point lying above the line!

Comment: this solutiong enlightens me.